# create bar chart using jfreechart by accessing data from 2 files and display data of file 1 and file 2 with different color

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

This is my code for displaying particular vale, eg. average of one file. Now i want to create bar chart for values from both the files, and indicate both with different colors. plz help:

public JFreeChart createBarChartFromCSV() {

```
    CSVFileReader csvReader = new CSVFileReader();
    List<String[]> csvData = null; 
    int indexOfAverage = 0;

    csvData = csvReader.getDataFromCSV(CSVFileReader.CSVFILENAME);

    for(String[] columnArray : csvData)
        for(int i = 0; i< columnArray.length; i++)
            if(columnArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("average")){
                indexOfAverage = i;
                break;
            }

    if(indexOfAverage == 0){
        System.err.println("Error retrieving data from CSV File !!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    JFreeChart barChart = generateBarChart(csvData, indexOfAverage);

    return barChart;
}


private JFreeChart generateBarChart(List<String[]> csvData, int columnIndex){

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    final String YAXIS_NAME = csvData.get(0)[columnIndex]; //value returned is "average"
    final String XAXIS_NAME = csvData.get(0)[0]; //value returned is "sampler_label"

    for(int i = 1; i < csvData.size() - 1; i++){

        long averageValue = Long.parseLong(csvData.get(i)[columnIndex]);
        String columnKey = csvData.get(i)[0];

        dataSet.setValue(averageValue, YAXIS_NAME, columnKey); // plot the graph
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between the average of 2 values", XAXIS_NAME, YAXIS_NAME, dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be making a separate dataset for each series and a separate chart for each dataset. Instead, you want one dataset with two series in a single chart. A `DefaultCategoryDataset` can have more that one series; each series is identified by the `rowKey` parameter in methods that alter the dataset. A good example to follow is [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), pictured [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html) with three series; the [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.65) comes with the distribution.

As an aside, you might also see if [`org.jfree.data.io.CSV`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/io/CSV.html) meets your requirements.